# Symfony 2.6 and Twitter Bootstrap: Unable to find template

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

My experience with Symfony frontend development is definitely limited. According to http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme I read that adding `bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig` as a twig form resource I should be able to essentially add Bootstrap themes to my form.

I presume I need to add some CSS files somewhere, maybe, but I haven't even got that far yet.

My problem is that after setting the reference as per the blog post:

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form:
        resources: ["bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig"]
```

in my `config.yml` file, I get the following "error stack" in Symfony:

```
[3/3] Twig_Error_Loader: Unable to find template "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" in kernel.root_dir/Resources/views/base.html.twig at line 10.
[2/3] InvalidArgumentException: Unable to find template "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" : "The file "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" does not exist (in: /path-to-symfony/app/Resources).
[1/3] InvalidArgumentException: The file "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" does not exist (in: /path-to-symfony/app/Resources).
```

I added twig-bridge via composer, just in case, but that doesn't seem to resolve it.

The only location of a file with that name that I can find is at:
`./vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig`.

If I put a breakpoint in the `vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php` file in the findTemplate method, a normal page goes through the process of iterating over `$this->paths['__main__']` which has two entries:

- path-to-symfony/app/Resources/views
- path-to-symfony/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form

I'm guessing that I need to somehow put the directory that the file is in into that paths array, but don't know how.

Can anyone point me in the direction of this (no doubt) simple solution?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you please show us the part of `Twig` where you are trying to use `Bootstrap` theme? I am currently working on a project that uses `Bootstrap` and I can tell that, apart from regular `Bootstrap`'s CSS file, it does not require any other...

Comment: @JovanPerovic: ATM I'm not actually trying to *use* it at all... just trying to get Symfony to recognise that I can use it (I think?) Either way, I've added the entry from my config.yml file if that helps?

Comment: I added the answer that might be helpful to you. Let me know if that worked...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the thing is that by defining `twig > form > resources`, you're telling `Symfony2` that you will have a custom resource located within your `./app/Resources` directory.

To resolve this, just copy/paste the file `./vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig` to `./app/Resources` and it should work.

Optionally, you could apply the theme to a each form individually, without touching `config.yml`. I do it that way, because I like to have a complete control over which form gets rendered how.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I can do this if I need to, but I added some additional details to my original question regarding trying to add the new path to the $this->paths['__main__'] array somehow? That to me seems more 'correct' but I really have no idea at this point.